# Uploading a PDF (or any file) under a course in Moodle Programmatically

Tags: api, pdf, moodle

i have been asked by my company to create an engine that will move all the files in our system (materials mostly PDF files) under Moodle courses.

i have all the files copied under a folder in the moodledata directory and i have an excel sheet that has all the file names and path and to which course (courses created under Moodle) is related.

what i need is how to use the File API to link a certain file to a certain course in order for the file to be shown under the course on Moodle.

any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a simple, quick answer to this, as the Moodle File API is only one half of the issue - the other half is adding an instance of the 'resource' module to the course, for each file, so the user has some way of accessing the file you have added.

For each files, you'll need to:

1. Create a draft files area
2. Add the file to a draft file area (using the files API and the $fs->create_file_from_pathname() function)
3. Call the function add_moduleinfo() with the details of the 'resource' module instance you want to create (this will then pass on to the function add_resource_instance, which will extract the file from the draft area and store it where it is wanted).

I can't go into much more detail without writing out all the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is still relevant for me!

@davos

> I can't go into much more detail without writing out all the code for you.

Really, now? You 're posting on StackOverflow dude, not on your university's message board :(

What I got is:

```php
$pdf_output = $dompdf->output();


$fs = get_file_storage();
$context = context_course::instance($course->id);
// Prepare file record object
$fileinfo = array(
    'contextid' => $context->id, // ID of context
    'component' => 'mod_mymod', // usually = table name
    'filearea' => 'mymod',     // usually = table name
    'itemid' => $id,   // usually = ID of row in table
    'filepath' => '/',           // any path beginning and ending in /
    'filename' => 'test.pdf'); // any filename

$file = $fs->get_file($fileinfo['contextid'], $fileinfo['component'], $fileinfo['filearea'],
        $fileinfo['itemid'], $fileinfo['filepath'], $fileinfo['filename']);

// Delete it if it exists
if ($file) {
    $file->delete();
}

$file = $fs->create_file_from_string($fileinfo, $pdf_output);

$file = $fs->get_file($fileinfo['contextid'], $fileinfo['component'], $fileinfo['filearea'],
                      $fileinfo['itemid'], $fileinfo['filepath'], $fileinfo['filename']);

// Read contents
if ($file) {
  $contents = $file->get_content();
  var_dump($contents);
}
```

And I can read the contents and dump them to the browser.
What I can't figure out is how to use "add_moduleinfo()" to store my pdf under a course.

The function signature is:

`function add_moduleinfo($moduleinfo, $course, $mform = null) {`

Alas, no explanation on what $moduleinfo should consist of, as moodle is undocumented.

Any hints are much welcome.

Comment: It's not that hard to find out what is needed for $moduleinfo - https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/course/modlib.php#L44 (as for 'undocumented' - Moodle may not have every single part of it fully documented, but there are a lot of PHPDocs and many bits in the Moodle docs - which you are welcome to extend, if you feel there is something missing).

Comment: Hey dude, 
thanks for the fast reply. I still don't get where I should put my $file..
Should it be part of $moduleinfo object? Shoud it be a new Resources object?

Comment: That's where you move from the generic data that gets passed in to add_moduleinfo for all activities and the specific data for the resource module. You need to put the file into a 'draft' file area, then pass on the id of that area as the 'files' field. Take a look at what I did in course/dndupload.php which then calls process_upload() in repository/upload/lib.php - which does more than you probably need, but is a good starting point.

Comment: You mean     protected function handle_file_upload() { ?
I 'll have a look and edit my response if I manage to pull it through. If not, I guess our operators will need to upload the pdfs manually... :/

Comment: Yes - inside handle_file_upload() - you can't use that directly, but you should be able to look at the way it gets the 'upload' repository to put the file into a draft area, then passes it on to mod_resource, which, in the function resource_dndupload_handle() stores 'draftitemid' into 'files'.

Comment: Hey, so now process_upload inside repository/upload/lib.php is throwing an error because my $_FILES is empty!
But it is supposed to be empty as I 'm creating the pdf programmatically. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clearer - you cannot use the code directly, but look through to see how the upload repository puts files into a draft area. You won't be able to use that function to get the file out of $_FILES, but you can set up a draft area in a similar way and copy the file into it. Then pass that draft id onto add_moduleinfo()

Comment: I see, I 'll try not to post here again!

Comment: hii @mitsest i have doubt on that one